# Create a file with a unicode title in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, fopen

I am saving the content and title from a WYSIWYG widget (screenshot below) in an SQL database. I am also creating a new file every time (php). My problem is that the new file has a weird name because of the unicode. I am trying to make it work with the unicoded version of the name.

This is my WYSIWYG form :

[image]

This is the part that saves the content and title in the database without any unicode issues because the UTF8 was set for the database fields :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `articles`(`Content`, `Article_Name`) VALUE ('$_POST[htmlcontent]','$_POST[articlename]')";
```

And this is the part that creates the file but the name has an issue with the unicode :

```
$myfile = fopen("$articlename.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

I first tried this:

```
$unicoded = iconv('windows-1250', 'utf-8', file_get_contents($articlename)); 
$myfile = fopen("$unicoded.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

and then this:

```
    function utf8_fopen_read($articlename) { 
    $fc = iconv('windows-1250', 'utf-8', $articlename); 
    $handle=fopen("$fc", "w"); 
    fwrite($handle, $fc); 
    fseek($handle, 0); 
    return $handle;
} 

    $myfile = utf8_fopen_read("$articlename.php");
```

They all return a file named "ÄŽâ€ ÄŽâ€ ÄŽâ€ ÄŽâ€.php" although it is supposed to be named "φφφ.php"

UPD:

I tried this and the console returns an empty string :

```
$fc = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $articlename); 
echo "<script>console.log('$fc')</script>";
```

I also tried this :

```
$name = urlencode($_POST["articlename"]) . ".php";
echo "<script>console.log('$name')</script>";
$myfile = fopen($name, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

but the name is now something like this '%CF%86.php'

Comment: what happens when you do this ? what do you expect to happen and what happen instead ?

Comment: @Rabin I changed the question a bit. If the file is named φφφ, it should return this name. Alternatively, I will try to convert it into latin with a function.

Comment: Which OS? Which version? Since PHP 7.1.0, PHP is able to handle Unicode filenames (it just needs to have default_charset = UTF-8). If this filename comes from the database, make sure you request the results in UTF-8 as well. (note that your SQL query has 2 SQL injections)

Comment: @julp  $name = urlencode($_POST["articlename"]) . ".php";
 echo "<script>console.log('$articlename')</script>";
 echo "<script>console.log('$name')</script>"; did not work either.

Comment: @CBroethe answers are not clear in the other questions. None of the solutions worked for me....

Comment: @julp Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25

Comment: @ApoloRadomer yea it will simply not work with that version

Comment: @Apolo Radomer Can you upgrade to PHP 7.1? If not, you cannot use a Unicode filename on Windows without using com or wfio extensions or (try to) convert your filename from UTF-8 to your local codepage (`$handle = fopen(iconv('utf-8', 'CP1250//TRANSLIT', $articlename), 'w')`? - same to read it)